# fedora 28 problem with vga_switcheroo and ati radeon issue

Tags: fedora, radeon, hybrid-graphics

I use fedora 28 with dell inspiron 5000. It has a hybrid graphics. 
I must boot without the power adapter plugged in. After I log in, I can plug the power adapter. Before shutdown I must remember to disconnect power cable otherwise linux freeze.

I have no problem using fedora only with battery. But when plug in the power adapter issues happened. For example vlc video player freeze, or lspci command fails.

I suppose the issue is into vga_switcheroo support.

It is possible to disable vga_switcheroo and use only integrated card?

This is the current status of vgaswitcheroo. The dis card could assume values between DynOff or DynPwr.

```
# cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
1:DIS: :DynOff:0000:01:00.0
```

This is an extract from dmesg showing the kernel error:

```
[ 1635.267484] [drm:atom_op_jump [amdgpu]] *ERROR* atombios stuck in loop for more than 5secs aborting
[ 1635.267507] [drm:amdgpu_atom_execute_table_locked [amdgpu]] *ERROR* atombios stuck executing 7C32 (len 272, WS 0, PS 4) @ 0x7C7B
[ 1635.267526] [drm:amdgpu_atom_execute_table_locked [amdgpu]] *ERROR* atombios stuck executing 6440 (len 70, WS 0, PS 8) @ 0x6466
[ 1635.267543] [drm:amdgpu_device_resume [amdgpu]] *ERROR* amdgpu asic init failed
[ 1635.619552] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: Wait for MC idle timedout !
[ 1635.980259] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: Wait for MC idle timedout !
[ 1635.990105] [drm] PCIE GART of 256M enabled (table at 0x000000F400040000).
[ 1635.993135] amdgpu: [powerplay] smu not running, upload firmware again 
[ 1635.996146] BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffffa8f1900c0fec
[ 1635.996149] PGD 27693d067 P4D 27693d067 PUD 0 
[ 1635.996152] Oops: 0002 [#1] SMP PTI
[ 1635.996154] Modules linked in: tun rfcomm fuse ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 nf_conntrack_netlink xt_addrtype br_netfilter overlay ccm nf_conntrack_netbios_ns nf_conntrack_broadcast xt_CT ip6t_rpfilter ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 xt_conntrack ip_set nfnetlink ebtable_nat ebtable_broute bridge stp llc ip6table_nat nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_nat_ipv6 ip6table_mangle ip6table_raw ip6table_security iptable_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat nf_conntrack libcrc32c iptable_mangle iptable_raw iptable_security ebtable_filter ebtables ip6table_filter ip6_tables vboxpci(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) cmac bnep sunrpc vfat fat arc4 uvcvideo btusb videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl btbcm videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btintel videobuf2_common bluetooth videodev snd_hda_codec_hdmi
[ 1635.996182]  rtsx_usb_ms media memstick ecdh_generic ath10k_pci ath10k_core intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp mac80211 snd_soc_skl kvm_intel snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_sst_dsp kvm snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core irqbypass dell_wmi dell_laptop crct10dif_pclmul hid_multitouch crc32_pclmul dell_smbios ath ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hda_codec_realtek iTCO_wdt wmi_bmof intel_cstate snd_compress iTCO_vendor_support snd_hda_codec_generic cfg80211 snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_uncore ac97_bus dell_wmi_descriptor intel_rapl_perf dcdbas dell_smm_hwmon snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec rfkill joydev snd_hda_core snd_hwdep ucsi_acpi typec_ucsi snd_seq typec wmi snd_seq_device int3403_thermal snd_pcm idma64 snd_timer mei_me snd processor_thermal_device mei pcc_cpufreq intel_soc_dts_iosf
[ 1635.996210]  int3400_thermal intel_lpss_pci pinctrl_sunrisepoint i2c_i801 intel_lpss intel_pch_thermal shpchp soundcore intel_hid int3402_thermal pinctrl_intel acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad sparse_keymap int340x_thermal_zone amdkfd amd_iommu_v2 amdgpu i915 chash gpu_sched i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper ttm rtsx_usb_sdmmc mmc_core drm r8169 crc32c_intel serio_raw mii rtsx_usb i2c_hid video ecryptfs
[ 1635.996225] CPU: 6 PID: 6228 Comm: lspci Tainted: G           OE     4.17.18-200.fc28.x86_64 #1
[ 1635.996226] Hardware name: Dell Inc. Inspiron 5570/0DRPKR, BIOS 1.0.6 10/25/2017
[ 1635.996266] RIP: 0010:smu7_populate_single_firmware_entry.isra.6+0x55/0xd0 [amdgpu]
[ 1635.996267] RSP: 0018:ffffa8d545f77b68 EFLAGS: 00010246
[ 1635.996269] RAX: 000000000000008c RBX: ffffa8f1900c0fec RCX: 0000000000000000
[ 1635.996270] RDX: ffffffffc088ab81 RSI: 0000000000000004 RDI: ffff9492ae3128f0
[ 1635.996271] RBP: 0000000000000003 R08: 0000000000033930 R09: 000000000000043f
[ 1635.996272] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffff9492ad1bb040
[ 1635.996273] R13: ffff9492ad1bc000 R14: 00000000000005fe R15: ffff9492b4d070a0
[ 1635.996275] FS:  00007fb62d10a740(0000) GS:ffff9492bf580000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[ 1635.996276] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[ 1635.996277] CR2: ffffa8f1900c0fec CR3: 000000016a85e002 CR4: 00000000003606e0
[ 1635.996278] Call Trace:
[ 1635.996315]  smu7_request_smu_load_fw+0x94/0x2e0 [amdgpu]
[ 1635.996350]  pp_resume+0x4b/0x80 [amdgpu]
[ 1635.996369]  amdgpu_device_ip_resume_phase2+0x51/0xb0 [amdgpu]
[ 1635.996389]  amdgpu_device_resume+0xb8/0x390 [amdgpu]
[ 1635.996392]  ? __pci_set_master+0x31/0xd0
[ 1635.996396]  ? vga_switcheroo_fini_domain_pm_ops+0x10/0x10
[ 1635.996414]  amdgpu_pmops_runtime_resume+0x6b/0xa0 [amdgpu]
[ 1635.996417]  pci_pm_runtime_resume+0x78/0xb0
[ 1635.996420]  __rpm_callback+0xca/0x210
[ 1635.996423]  ? vga_switcheroo_fini_domain_pm_ops+0x10/0x10
[ 1635.996424]  rpm_callback+0x1f/0x70
[ 1635.996426]  ? vga_switcheroo_fini_domain_pm_ops+0x10/0x10
[ 1635.996428]  rpm_resume+0x560/0x780
[ 1635.996430]  __pm_runtime_resume+0x47/0x70
[ 1635.996432]  pci_read_config+0x95/0x290
[ 1635.996435]  ? _cond_resched+0x15/0x30
[ 1635.996438]  ? __kmalloc+0x19a/0x230
[ 1635.996441]  kernfs_fop_read+0xac/0x180
[ 1635.996444]  __vfs_read+0x36/0x170
[ 1635.996446]  vfs_read+0x8a/0x140
[ 1635.996449]  ksys_pread64+0x61/0xa0
[ 1635.996452]  do_syscall_64+0x5b/0x160
[ 1635.996455]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
[ 1635.996458] RIP: 0033:0x7fb62c818627
[ 1635.996459] RSP: 002b:00007ffd120a37b8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000011
[ 1635.996461] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 00007fb62c818627
[ 1635.996462] RDX: 0000000000000040 RSI: 000055e746c9daa0 RDI: 0000000000000003
[ 1635.996463] RBP: 0000000000000040 R08: 00007fb62cd0e6d2 R09: 00007ffd120a2c70
[ 1635.996465] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 000055e746ca6110
[ 1635.996466] R13: 000055e746c9daa0 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
[ 1635.996467] Code: 48 89 e7 48 89 e2 f3 48 ab 49 8b 3c 24 89 f0 0f b6 b0 80 4d 97 c0 48 8b 07 48 8b 40 40 e8 04 52 36 eb 85 c0 75 4a 0f b7 44 24 02 <66> 89 2b 48 c7 43 0c 00 00 00 00 66 89 43 02 48 8b 44 24 10 48 
[ 1635.996521] RIP: smu7_populate_single_firmware_entry.isra.6+0x55/0xd0 [amdgpu] RSP: ffffa8d545f77b68
[ 1635.996522] CR2: ffffa8f1900c0fec
[ 1635.996523] ---[ end trace 5595bb431d82770d ]---
```

Thank you